# How to centralise a button div

Tags: css

I want to centralise a button or a tag within the line it is on (by themselves).

I've written this CSS which makes it yellow, puts a border around it etc but it is always left aligned.  How do I centralise it?

```
a.butt, button.butt {
   border: 1px solid #ffff01;
   background-color: transparent;
   height:50px;
   cursor:pointer;
   padding-left: 40px;
   padding-right: 40px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-align: center;
   color: #ffff01;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

several ways to do this, but maybe

```
a.butt, button.butt {
 border: 1px solid #ffff01;
 background-color: transparent;
 height:50px;
 cursor:pointer;
 padding-left: 40px;
 padding-right: 40px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 color: #ffff01;

 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: ??px;
}
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding `text-align:center;` to parent `<div>`

Example here https://jsfiddle.net/uy4u781d/

Answer (score 0):

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:150px; //width as you want
display:block;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.